# Spring-boot field is null

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a small maven3-project with spring-boot. when i run the project, i get a Nullpointerexception.

My Service:

```
@Transactional
@Service("serviceA")
public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {

    ....
```

A part of my controller My controller:

```
@Path("/path")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AController {

    @Autowired
    ServiceA serviceA;

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    public Response test(A a) {

        serviceA.createEntity(a);
    }
```

My Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.y.server")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(value = { C.class, D.class })
public class ServerConfiguration {

some beans declarations for datasource, entitymanager ...
```

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().configure(new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)).run(args);
    }
}
```

The controller are in the com.y.server package. I got an NullPointerException when i send a request to localhost:8080/project/path/all.

Any ideas?
Thank
Cheers

Comment: It doesn't look like Spring is managing the `AController` object. Look into Spring/Jersey integration. There might be something for boot as well.

Comment: It's generally considered to be bad practice to use field autowiring. But some break points in and see what's being inited where - you likely have a component scan wrong or some such.

Comment: i added a resource config and registried the controllers but i got the same errors.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see your stacktrace of the NPE.

Comment: ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3] container.ContainerResponse: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.y.server.AController.test(AController.java:67)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)